# Mysql Date Column: Why index key sometimes used and sometimes not?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with an indexed column named `date_c` with type `Date`. The problem is when I query something like this

`explain select * from table where date_c > '2021-06-29'`

the `possible_keys` is `idx_..75` and `key` is `idx_..75` too but when I change comparison like this:

`explain select * from table where date_c < '2021-06-29'`

in this case `possible_keys` is `idx_..75` again but `key` is `NULL`

Why is that? Also I tried these but got the same results:

`explain select * from table where date_c > DATE(NOW()) - 2 DAY`  **key is not NULL**

`explain select * from table where date_c > DATE(NOW()) - 20 DAY`  **key is NULL**

Why mysql does not use `possible_keys` sometimes?

Comment: *Selectivity* maybe? The cost of using an index may be much higher than reading the whole table from beginning to end, when you are selecting more than 5% of the rows. What percentage of the rows is each query selecting?

Comment: @TheImpaler Well that makes sense now you mentioned it. I only have 13 rows in the table and I checked now queries  where rows are  4 or 5 the index key is used in them however where result rows were 12 or 13, index key is not used.Is it okay?

Comment: I was thinking in terms of thousands (or even millions of rows). When you have less than 1000 rows the engine may spend more time planning and evaluating plans than actually executing the query. 13 rows, are not really representative.

Comment: @TheImpaler Well I'm in development stage

Comment: Makes sense, and your question is a valid one. Now, if you want to make sure I would suggest producing 10k rows using a query with random values (`RAND()` maybe) and try it again then.